# Cannot use mouseover on specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, css-tables

I'm trying to display an alert when the use put the mouse over a `tr` of `.scrollable` class, this is the html:

```
<table class="results" id="resource-container" style="height: 769px;">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="scrollable">
                        <tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 10px"><div></tr>
            </tbody></table>
```

and this is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.scrollable > tr').mouseover(function()
  {
     alert("hello");
  });
});
```

A complete example is available on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/1025/).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is your div wrapping that tr?  That is invalid markup!

Comment: that div allow scrollable table

Comment: But your `tr` needs to be inside of a `table` element.  It cannot be as you have posted.  Check the validity of your markup - obviously this is not valid markup.

Comment: there is a table, I just saw that I missing to add this in my example

Comment: I hope its not outside of the outer div because that too is invalid markup - case in point - you cannot have a div floating outside of tr's.  They need to be inside of a tr in order to be valid markup.

Comment: Your edit is still invalid markup.  You may want to learn how html works before trying to do what you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `tr` element works only if it is in a `table` wrapper - also note that you would need to drop the `>` in the selector and use this - `.scrollable > tbody > tr` or `.scrollable tr`.

See demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.scrollable tr').mouseover(function() {
    console.log("hello");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="scrollable">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 10px">
      <div>
        <strong>foo</strong>
        <br>test
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I missing to add the table structure, could you please check the update?

Comment: this not working 'cause scrollable class is on div not on the table as your example

Comment: ohh, just noticed, a `tr` inside a `td` is also invalid syntax - you can use the `div` inside the `td`...

Comment: the tr is inside the div of td, there is no way to achieve this?

Comment: no, you must use nested tables - use `table` inside `td` and then inside the `table` you can keep the `tr`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132321/discussion-between-againme-and-kukkuz).